# How can I check HttpListenerRequest connection is still open?

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to check if the connection is still open. If it isn't, I'll stop the process.

```
         //Process request code goes here

         while (!isComplete) {
            //Check HttpListenerRequest if connection is still open...

            if (IsTimedOut && !timeoutTriggered)
            {
                timeoutTriggered = triggerTimeout();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        //Process response code goes here
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Question is not clear at all.Please create https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem with a write/flush pair. 
Flush throws an exception when the connection has closed.

```
try
{
    //Checks whether the connection is still open
    var encoding = Encoding.Default;
    byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(encoding, Encoding.UTF8, encoding.GetBytes(" "));
    listenerContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length);
    listenerContext.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    eventStream.TriggerEvent(new ActionEventArgs(this, ActionEventStreamer.SYSTEM_CANCEL));
    break;
}
```